# Rstudio framing not allowed

Tags: r, rstudio

When attempting to launch an app "`runApp()`" from OSX with Rstudio Version 0.99.467 – © 2009-2015 RStudio, Inc.

I get the warning pop up "For security reason, framing is not allowed".  Is there an option to temporarily modify and allow framing? Am still in testing stage so I'd like to tinker with the app in RStudio before launching it on the server?

[image]